# How to get callback or return value from async JS function to Dart in Flutter Web?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am trying to execute **JS** native code in Flutter web. I got the way to call **JS** function from **Dart** but could not find any workaround to get the result back from **JS** to **Dart**.

Below are the JS code and Dart code which I was trying to achieve in different ways but didn't get any success.

### **JS Code:**

```js
    let fileHandle;
    let finalResult;

    async function fileOpen() {

        [fileHandle] = await window.showOpenFilePicker();
        const file = await fileHandle.getFile();
        console.log('File info ----> ', file);

        if (file != null) {
            const parser = new window.AppInfoParser(file);
            const result = await parser.parse();
            console.log('app info ----> ', result);
            console.log('icon base64 ----> ', result.icon);
            
            finalResult = result;
            
        } else {
            finalResult = 'File not selected';
            console.log('File not selected')
        }

        return finalResult;
        // return Promise.resolve(finalResult)
    }
```

### **Dart Code:**

**Example 1:** Simply call JS function without callback.

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;

// Call below on any click event
js.context.callMethod('fileOpen')
```

**Example 2:** Getting error before JS code is executed. `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: jsPromise.then is not a function at Object.promiseToFuture (js_util.dart:275:35)`.

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;
import 'package:js/js_util.dart';

// Call below on any click event
dynamic result = await promiseToFuture<dynamic>(js.context.callMethod('fileOpen'));
```

**Example 3:** Getting error after JS code is executed. `NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'obj[$toString]'` OR `Expected a value of type 'Future<dynamic>', but got one of type 'LegacyJavaScriptObject'`.

```dart
import 'package:js/js_util.dart';
import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS('fileOpen')
external dynamic fileOpen;

// Call below on any click event
dynamic result = await promiseToFuture(fileOpen());
```

Need a way to get the result back to dart.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `NoSuchMethodError` points you in the right direction. In your JS code `fileOpen` is a function, in your dart code it's just a variable.

You're missing the `()` at the end: `fileOpen()`

Edit: Just saw you had opened an issue at github which already got resolved: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/50530